# How to obtain a new Api.AccessToken after user has log out from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using  [Facebook Graph Toolkit](http://fgt.codeplex.com/)  and doing ASP.NET website development.

There's a Api object in this toolkit and there's this Api.AccessToken that is giving me a headache!

Here goes the problem description:

1. User visits my website (say, this case is IE 8 browser).
2. User clicks on Login to FB (in order for my App to retrieve his FB info via the Api graph).
3. User logins with his FB credential and Approve the App.
4. User is redirected back to the same page that he clicks on the Login to FB button (in step 2, because the button, will invoke the method RedirectToFacebookAuthorization() ).
5. User then logs out from Facebook.com (my website hasn't implement any log out button for this scenario).
6. User has successfully logged out from his FB account, he revisit my website.
7. My website throws out an exception message as below:

   ```
         OAuthException : Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out
   ```
8. The user clicks on Login to FB button on my website but no response (actually, the response is the exception message throwing back again). Even if he opens another IE browser window and click on the button, no response too. I've attempted the try/catch and caught the exception only to inform the user that he has already log out from my website and facebook.

So the situation is how to make the user to obtain another valid Access Token... I can only think of it is that the user has to click on the Login to FB button on my website but the (previous) Access Token is already invalid and cannot be overwritten by the 2nd attempt to login. And the only way that I have tested in order for the user to re-login to my website using his FB is to close the browser Window (but I don't want such user experience because user doesn't know that he has to close the browser and open it again to login to my website).

Even if the user has chosen to go to Facebook.com and login from there, and then revisit my website, he is still not authenticated and not allow to proceed further on my website.

Please enlighten me on what to resolve the above problem. Is the approach that I'm using is wrong?

---

**EDIT: added the codes for further explanation**

Here's my code and

```
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RequireLogin = false;
    ExtendedPermissions = "offline_access,user_about_me,user_activities,user_birthday,";
}

protected void btn_fbLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (Api == null)
            RedirectToFacebookAuthorization();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Failed to login to Facebook.");
    }
}

protected void btn_FBMerge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getEmail", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter demai = new SqlParameter("@dem", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(demai);
        cmd.Parameters["@dem"].Value = lbl_FBEmail.Text;
        SqlDataReader Dr;
        con.Open();
        Dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (Dr.Read())
        {
            if ((lbl_FBEmail.Text == Dr[9].ToString()))
            {
                // grab each column from DR and place to asp:Labels...
            }
            else
            {
                // show some error message
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // display another division and put the FB email, first name, last name and gender to 4 more labels
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Attempt to Merge Facebook failed");
    }
}

protected void btn_Confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("mergeFB", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter dsomeID = new SqlParameter("@someID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        SqlParameter dfbID = new SqlParameter("@fbID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(dsomeID);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(dfbID);
        cmd.Parameters["@someid"].Value = lbl_MyID.Text;
        cmd.Parameters["@fbID"].Value = lbl_FBID.Text;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Response.Write("Your Facebook account has been added to mywebsite account successfully");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Attempt to Merge Facebook failed");
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when the button (method is btn_FBMerge_Click) is clicked and IE gives me forever respond and Firefox give me the error that I mentioned earlier.

If I didn't include the offline_access permission, when I click on the btn_FBMerge_Click button, I don't get that strange problem. Then, this still leads to the main problem which is the Api.AccessToken is invalid issue that I mentioned in my original problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the users token is no longer valid, you will need to show the login button to get a new valid session token.  If you want to get a token that doesn't expire, you can prompt the user for "offline_access" extended permission.  But only do that if its absolutely necessary as people don't tend to like to give apps that permission without good reason.

Comment: I have also tried adding the offline_access into the extended permission in the code-behind. It's giving me really weird behaviour whereby (say user has already approved app with this permission) after user sign out from FB, and then login again at my website by clicking on the Login to FB button, the respond takes forever.

Comment: In IE, the responds takes forever, but in Firefox, it throws me this error
"The page isn't redirecting properly
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."
what did I do wrong here??

Comment: Sounds like you have some kind of infinite redirect loop going on. Without seeing any code its hard to guess.